# "At step" or "in step"

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, prepositions, writing, formality

When I searched I found many usages of both "in step" and "at step". For example, Google returns:

- "at each step" — about 55,000,000 results
- "in each step" — about 45,000,000 results

But which one is better to use in scientific papers?

Comment: In this particular instance, it doesn't seem to make much of a difference (without more detail).  If your question isn't simply one of curiosity, could you provide the complete sentence in question?

Answer (score 12):

While very similar, and often used interchangeably, there is a technical difference between the two.

*"In each step"* implies that something is done or happens as part of the process. *"At each step"* is for something done additionally to the process.

> Assembling the furniture consists of seven steps. In each step a new piece is added to the assembly.
>
> Creating a report takes three steps. At each step the author is required to check with a reviewer that it has been done correctly.